# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: jsp, scriptlet

Hi in my jsp page i am testing a condition

```
<jsp:scriptlet>

  if (session.getAttribute("empid") != null && session.getAttribute("empid") != "")
{
.......
}
```

But i am getting compiler error.

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

any body know how to solve this?

Comment: You can easily avoid the error by putting your code in a servlet, where it belongs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a bit on the type of JSP page you are using.

If you use normal JSP pages, you can choose between replacing your `<jsp:scriptlet>` tags with `<% %>` or escaping all XML entities (like `&` as `&amp;` or `<` as `&lt;`).

However, if you are using JSPX (also called JSP document), your only choice is to escape the XML entities.

Comment: i am not using <% %> . i am following jsp style

Comment: `<% %>` doesn't work in JSPX. You have to use `<jsp:scriptlet>`, exactly like OP did. The remainder of your answer is right.

Comment: @BalusC I've updated the answer and provided some more information.

Answer (score 1):

"Facelets is a XML based view technology which uses XHTML+XML to generate HTML output. XML has five special characters which has special treatment by the XML parser:

< the start of a tag.

> the end of a tag.
>   " the start and end of an attribute value.
>   ' the alternative start and end of an attribute value.
>   & the start of an entity (which ends with ;).
>   In case of & which is not followed by # (e.g.   or  ), the XML parser is implicitly looking for one of the predefined entity names such as lt, gt, amp, etc. However, in your particular case, you was using & as a JavaScript operator, not as an XML entity. This totally explains the XML parsing error you got:

The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

In essence, you're writing JavaScript code in the wrong place, a XML document instead of a JS file, so you should be escaping all XML special characters accordingly. The & must be escaped as &.

So, in your particular case, the

if (session.getAttribute("empid") != null && session.getAttribute("empid")
must become

if (session.getAttribute("empid") != null && session.getAttribute("empid")
to make it XML-valid."

taken from [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)

Answer (score 1):

With regular javascript you can wrap the following around you JS:
`//<![CDATA[.... //]]>`

Give that a shot.