# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

Tags: javascript, xml, jsf, xhtml, facelets

I want to put a packman game on my *.xhtml page.(I am using jsf 2 and primefaces 3.5)

However,

when I "translated" the html page in xhtml I get an error at this script:

```
    <script>

    var el = document.getElementById("pacman");

    if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage && 
        Modernizr.audio && (Modernizr.audio.ogg || Modernizr.audio.mp3)) {
      window.setTimeout(function () { PACMAN.init(el, "./"); }, 0);
    } else { 
      el.innerHTML = "Sorry, needs a decent browser<br /><small>" + 
        "(firefox 3.6+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10+ and Safari 4+)</small>";
    }
  </script>
```

At line:

```
if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage &&
```

i get:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity
>   reference.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 267, accepted):

All answers posted so far are giving the right solutions, however no one answer was able to properly explain the underlying cause of the concrete problem.

Facelets is a XML based view technology which uses XHTML+XML to generate HTML output. XML has five special characters which has special treatment by the XML parser:

- `<` the start of a tag.
- `>` the end of a tag.
- `"` the start and end of an attribute value.
- `'` the alternative start and end of an attribute value.
- `&` the start of an entity (which ends with `;`).

In case of `&` which is not followed by `#` (e.g. `&#160;`, `&#xA0;`, etc), the XML parser is implicitly looking for one of the five [predefined entity names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) `lt`, `gt`, `amp`, `quot` and `apos`, or any [manually defined entity name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/error-parsing-page-xhtml-error-tracedline-42-the-entity-nbsp-was-referenc). However, in your particular case, you was using `&` as a JavaScript operator, not as an XML entity. This totally explains the XML parsing error you got:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference

In essence, you're writing JavaScript code in the wrong place, a XML document instead of a JS file, so you should be escaping all XML special characters accordingly. The `&` must be escaped as `&amp;`.

So, in your particular case, the

```
if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage &&
```

must become

```
if (Modernizr.canvas &amp;&amp; Modernizr.localstorage &amp;&amp;
```

to make it XML-valid.

However, this makes the JavaScript code harder to read and maintain. In case when you want to continue using `&` instead of `&amp;` in JavaScript code in a XML document, then you should be placing the JavaScript code in a character data (CDATA) block. Thus, in JSF terms, that would be:

```
<h:outputScript>
    <![CDATA[
        // ...
    ]]>
</h:outputScript>
```

The XML parser will interpret the block's contents as "plain vanilla" character data and not as XML and hence interpret the XML special characters "as-is".

But, much better is to just put the JS code in its own JS file which you include by `<script src>`, or in JSF terms, the `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<h:outputScript name="onload.js" target="body" />
```

*(note the `target="body"`; this way JSF will automatically render the `<script>` at the very end of `<body>`, regardless of where `<h:outputScript>` itself is located, hereby achieving the same effect as with `window.onload` and `$(document).ready()`; so you don't need to use those anymore in that script)*

This way you don't need to worry about XML-special characters in your JS code. As an additional bonus, this gives you the opportunity to let the browser cache the JS file so that total response size is smaller.

#### See also:

- [Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13012327/the-entity-nbsp-was-referenced-but-not-declared/)
- [Is it possible to use JSF+Facelets with HTML 4/5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935759/is-it-possible-to-use-jsffacelets-with-html-4-5)
- [How to reference CSS / JS / image resource in Facelets template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367421/how-to-reference-resource-in-facelets-template)

Comment: Shouldn't the ![CDATA[ be a commented line? Just curious.

Comment: @Nacho321: Only if the content type is wrongly set to `application/xhtml+xml` instead of `text/html`, which in turn would cause several failures in some browsers, mainly MSIE. See also "Writing JavaScript for XHTML" document. In JSF, you don't need to if you use `<f:view contentType="text/html">` instead of letting JSF/webbrowser auto-guess do the work. See further also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xhtml/info

Comment: NOTE: This does not only occur for Javascipt operations (since I correctly use `&amp;&amp;` in an if-statement one line above my error), but also on comment line; my error was on `// TODO KevinC & Victor: some todo` (now it's changed to `and`..). Also, thanks a lot for this post. I came across it before as a fix for the same problem as OP.

Comment: your answer is wrong. it should be &amp; instead of &amp;&amp;

Comment: @funky-nd: I guess you confused it with &amp;amp;. Now re-read the answer with this in mind.

Answer (score 17):

You need to add a CDATA tag inside of the script tag, unless you want to manually go through and escape all XHTML characters (e.g. `&` would need to become `&amp;`).  For example:

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[
var el = document.getElementById("pacman");

if (Modernizr.canvas && Modernizr.localstorage && 
    Modernizr.audio && (Modernizr.audio.ogg || Modernizr.audio.mp3)) {
  window.setTimeout(function () { PACMAN.init(el, "./"); }, 0);
} else { 
  el.innerHTML = "Sorry, needs a decent browser<br /><small>" + 
    "(firefox 3.6+, Chrome 4+, Opera 10+ and Safari 4+)</small>";
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

The parser is expecting some HTML content, so it sees `&` as the beginning of an entity, like `&egrave;`.

Use this workaround:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
Javascript code here
// ]]>
</script>
```

so you specify that the code is not HTML text but just data to be used as is.

Answer (score 5):

Do

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
    /* script */
//]]></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use XHTML, for some reason, note that [XHTML 1.0 C 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_4) says: “Use external scripts if your script uses < or & or ]]> or --.” That is, don’t embed script code inside a `script` element but put it into a separate JavaScript file and refer to it with `<script src="foo.js"></script>`.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone from Blogger arrives, I had this problem when using `Beautify` extension in VSCode. Don´t use it, don´t `beautify` it.