# Primefaces Gmap with JSF

Tags: google-maps, jsf, primefaces

As I am using Primefaces and JSF and use the `Gmap` component, I need to put in the head of the page something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false">
</script>
```

The problem is that, doing so, I obtain an error as "&sensor" is interpreted as an XML entity.
Any help welcome.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `&` for `&amp;` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)

Comment: In future, please search around based on the exact error message instead of an observation. Using the exact error message as search keyword gives the best results.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to type v=3 anymore.
I'm using:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```