# Error Parsing /page.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 42] Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "id"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

When using the following JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$("#service_container").append("<p id=\"text\">SomeText</p>")
```

I got the following error:

```
Error Parsing /dashboard.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 140] Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "id".
```

This is the stacktrace:

```
javax.faces.view.facelets.FaceletException: Error Parsing /dashboard.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 140] Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "id".
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doCompile(SAXCompiler.java:456)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.SAXCompiler.doMetadataCompile(SAXCompiler.java:439)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.Compiler.metadataCompile(Compiler.java:130)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:503)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.access$200(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:106)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:205)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:203)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:97)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache$2.newInstance(DefaultFaceletCache.java:92)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache$1.call(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at com.sun.faces.util.ExpiringConcurrentCache.get(ExpiringConcurrentCache.java:114)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:146)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletCache.getViewMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletCache.java:63)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:316)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getMetadataFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:246)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:138)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at com.omegathings.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I made sure that jQuery is working by appending elements without attributes.
Also the `[service_container]` id is correct and assigned to `[ul]` HTML element.
Are jQuery and Facelets parser not getting along for some reason or am I missing something?

Comment: Either wrap the JavaScript/jQuery code in an ugly `CDATA` tag (`//<![CDATA[.............// ]]>`) or move it to an external JavaScript file and include that file to an XHTML file of your interest using `<h:outputScript library="library" name="path/to/js" target="head"/>` or using a plain `<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/js"></script>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology which uses XHTML+XML to generate HTML output. XML has five special characters which has special treatment by the XML parser:

- `<` the start of a tag.
- `>` the end of a tag.
- `"` the start and end of an attribute value.
- `'` the alternative start and end of an attribute value.
- `&` the start of an entity (which ends with `;`).

In your particular case, the unescaped `<` in a JavaScript string triggered the XML parser to start a tag. The `id` is recognized as a tag attribute and then it will search for an open quote like `"` or `'`. However, in your particular case, you was using `\` to escape it as a quote for a JavaScript string. This totally explains the XML parsing error you got:

> Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an element type "id"

In essence, you're writing JavaScript code in the wrong place, a XML document instead of a JS file, so you should be escaping all XML special characters accordingly.

So, essentially, the

```
$("#service_container").append("<p id=\"text\">SomeText</p>")
```

must become

```
$("#service_container").append("&lt;p id=&quot;text&quot;&gt;SomeText&lt;/p&gt;")
```

to make it XML-valid. Noted should be that some parsers are more forgiving in some character sequences, with the most parsers you could just keep using `>` instead of escaping it.

However, this makes the JavaScript code harder to read and maintain. As stated in Mozilla Developer Network's excellent document [Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML), you should be placing the JavaScript code in a character data (CDATA) block. Thus, in JSF terms, that would be:

```
<h:outputScript>
    <![CDATA[
        // ...
    ]]>
</h:outputScript>
```

The XML parser will interpret the block's contents as "plain vanilla" character data and not as XML and hence interpret the XML special characters "as-is".

But, much better is to just put the JS code in its own JS file which you include by `<script src>`, or in JSF terms, the `<h:outputScript>`.

```
<h:outputScript name="functions.js" target="head" />
```

This way you don't need to worry about XML-special characters in your JS code.

#### See also:

- [Error parsing XHTML: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4338538/error-parsing-xhtml-the-content-of-elements-must-consist-of-well-formed-charact/4338816#4338816)
- [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference/16328808#16328808)
- [Writing JavaScript for XHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Writing_JavaScript_for_XHTML)