# How to add another statement in IF with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I combine primefaces with SVG and onclick. If I write just the first part "if($(window).width()>800){PF('dlg_p').show();}" there is no problem, but if I want to add another  restriction don't work.

```
<svg width="200" height="210" onclick="if($(window).width()>600)&&($(window).height()>600){PF('dlg_s').show();}">
```

But the console gives me an error I can't solve:

Error Traced [line 313] The entity name must appear immediately after '&' in the entity reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your code, see expanded here:

```
if(
    $(window).width()>600
) //<- this closes the if!
&&(
    $(window).height()>600
){PF('dlg_s').show();}
```

Instead you probably want:

```
if(
    ($(window).width()>600)
    &&
    ($(window).height()>600)
){PF('dlg_s').show();}
```

**Edit**: this is apparently only one half of the solution (as there are 2 mistakes in the code), see the question of which this is a duplicate: [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)).

Comment: Huh??? how can this be an accepted answer for this problem?

Comment: Because there are two errors and each of you solved one of them.

Comment: @Kukeltje your solution is indeed needed too (besides this), I just typed up this answer as this mistake stood out immediately for me. A +1 there and an attribution is all I can offer now.

Comment: :-). It is not about the +x attribution, and compliment that the other error stood out immediately (a little surprising that the other error with an explicit mentioning did not stand out ;-) ). I'll remove my answer since it is already market as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote it here if statement ends after "600)". Check you braces. It should be like

```
onclick="if($(window).width()>600 && $(window).height()>600){PF('dlg_s').show();}">
```