# the entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. javascript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I am trying to make an Ajax call in my `Thymeleaf` page. So here is the code

```
<script>
        function getTodayRequest(){
            console.log("here is today");
            var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                document.getElementById("received").innerHTML=
                    this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET","URI",true);
        }

</script>
```

So it complins with  the error:

```
the entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference. java
```

and i have changed the `&` with `&amp;` and now it looks like:

```
if(this.readyState==4 &amp;&amp; this.status==200)
```

but now again it complains with:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

In the second `&amp;`

How can i handle it?

Comment: I'm no expert but afaik you could wrap the script code in an html comment, i.e. `<script><!-- code //--></script>`.

Comment: Unfortunately `&amp;` is not a valid operator in JS. That is an HTML entity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference)

Comment: What Doctype are you using? Using cdata is necessary in HTML5... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/66837/when-is-a-cdata-section-necessary-within-a-script-tag

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and I've resolved adding `scripting inling` from thymelefeaf reference documentation.

So, try to put your `javascript` code between `<script th:inline="javascript">` like next:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
     function getTodayRequest(){
            console.log("here is today");
            var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
                document.getElementById("received").innerHTML=
                    this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xhttp.open("GET","URI",true);
        }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```