# NonStringException in FreeMarker template when output_format is set

Tags: xml, freemarker

I have a FreeMarker template where I want to specify the output format in order to escape some characters in my XML files. The template example looks as below:

```
<#ftl output_format="XML">
<#assign field1>
   TestField&1&
</#assign>
<#assign field2>
   <#if field1?trim?length == 0>
      TestField&1&
   <#else>
      TestField&2&
   </#if>
</#assign>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FIELD2>${field2}</FIELD2>
```

The transformation works fine (except the escaping), unless I put the `<#ftl output_format="XML">` directive in my template. After that I get a NonStringException:

> freemarker.core.NonStringException: For "?trim" left-hand operand: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this has evaluated to a markup_output (wrapper: f.c.TemplateXMLOutputModel):
> ==> field1  [in template "Test.ftl" at line 6, column 9]

Basically `field1?trim?length` does not work, because `field1` is not evaluated as a string anymore.

Without the output format directive everything woks as expected.
FreeMarker version I'm using is **[2.3.26-incubating](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.freemarker/freemarker/2.3.26-incubating)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`markup_string`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_expert.html#ref_builtin_markup_string) builtin, which returns the markup stored inside a markup output value as string.

```
<#ftl output_format="XML">
<#assign field1>
    TestField&1&
</#assign>
<#assign field2>
    <#if field1?markup_string?trim?length == 0>
        TestField&1&
    <#else>
        TestField&2&
    </#if>
</#assign>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FIELD2>${field2}</FIELD2>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works - appreciate you assistance here!

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this error with XML [outputformat](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_outputformat.html) you can assign field1 with string value:

```
<#ftl output_format="XML">
<#assign field1 ="TestField&1&"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but unfortunately it does not work neither. The result of such assignment is `org.xmlunit.XMLUnitException: The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference`

Comment: @DimaSan this is XML issue, do you mean to use &amp;? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303779/the-entity-name-must-immediately-follow-the-in-the-entity-reference

Comment: @DimaSan Does that `XMLUnitException` occur after you did `${field2}`? Then maybe auto escaping is turned off there, which is not recommended. (Or, `XMLUnit` tries to validate the template itself as XML? Although then it would choke on `<#` as well.)